# Make JWT (JSON Web Token) Last Longer or Other Alternatives For Flutter App

Tags: django, authentication, python-requests, jwt

I have a django backend that user the Django Rest Framework. I have Django Rest APIs set up, that are specific for every user. I then also use JSON Web Tokens to be able to authenticate Users via my mobile Flutter Frontend.

I then use the token I get on login in every request which works great! My problem is when the token runs out the user has to login again for this all to work.

Is there any way I could make the JSON Web Tokens to last longer then the standard time of like 5 minutes???

Token Code in Django:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',),
}
```

Different URLS (also the get-token url):

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('project/', include('project.urls')),
  path('studyplan/', include('studyplan.urls')),
  path('get-token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
  path('refresh-token/', TokenRefreshView.as_view())
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at official documentation: https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt
There is a specific configuration to do that.

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
```

**ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME**
*A datetime.timedelta object which specifies how long access tokens are valid. This timedelta value is added to the current UTC time during token generation to obtain the token's default "exp" claim value.*